# How to resolve Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a BeforeTest annotated setBrowser error

Tags: java, testng

I have @BeforeTest and @AfterTest Annotations used. Please find below code

```
WebDriverFactory wd =  new WebDriverFactory();

    //@Parameters({"browserName","appURL"})
    @BeforeTest
    public void setBrowser(String browserName, String appURL){
        wd.setDriver("chrome", "https:URL");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown()
    {
        wd.closeBrowser();
    }
```

And getting below error

AILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setBrowser
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Can inject only one of  into a BeforeTest annotated setBrowser.
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:244)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:172)

Comment: Is your question heading and error stack trace identical? I don't see `<ITestContext, XmlTest>` in your error stack trace. FYI, the exact error stack trace helps us most to debug your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The reason for the error is pretty straight forward:

Your `@BeforeTest` annotated method is accepting two String parameters, but you aren't injecting those parameters via the `@Parameters` annotation (I am seeing that in the code that you shared, you have commented it out).

TestNG is basically complaining that it doesn't know what to provide as values for those two String parameters, and TestNG can ONLY natively inject either a

- `ITestContext` object for which your `@BeforeTest` annotated method signature would look like `public void setBrowser(ITestContext context){` (or)
- `XmlTest` object for which your `@BeforeTest` annotated method signature would look like `public void setBrowser(XmlTest xmlTest){`

So you would need to either uncomment your `@Parameters` annotation on top of the `setBrowser()` method, or change its signature to one of the above two variants.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Krishnan, it can resolve your problem; however, if you do not want to use one of ITestContext or XmlTest, there is another simple solution.

Just do not use any parameter in setBrowser function that was associated with @Parameters.  By deleting these parameters, your test will run and you will not observe this error.

Secondly, for browser name and app url you should use config.properties in this case.